# How to create User access level workspace using Jackrabbit?

Tags: apache, jackrabbit, content-repository

I want to create user level workspace using `content repository and Apache JackRabbit`

**I want to achieve :**

How to create User access level workspace using Jackrabbit ??

if i have created the workspace then other person can't be able to access.

Kindly help me in this .